# How to show this series grows like $\sqrt{\log{x}}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

Let $b_n$ denote the function such that
$$b_n=\begin{cases}1 & n \text{ is the sum of two squares}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
How do I show the sum $$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{b_n}{n} = O(\sqrt{\log{x}})$$? I need a fairly elementary proof which uses the fact that about half the primes are congruent to $1$ mod $4$ in the sum.

Comment: Why do you think that an elementary proof exists ?

Comment: Sieve methods are technically elementary, but quite complicated. Deriving this fact from the asymptotic formula for the number of sums of two squares up to $x$, via partial summation, is simple but invokes a deep result. Can you be more specific about what elements you do or don't want in a proof?

Comment: @GregMartin is referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau–Ramanujan_constant) [result](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-RamanujanConstant.html).

Comment: @GregMartin I'm using this to try to prove the asymptotic formula you mentioned, I've got an upper bound $\prod_{p \leq x , p \equiv 1 mod 4} (1-\frac{1}{p})^{-1} \prod_{p \leq x , p \equiv 3 mod 4} (1-\frac{1}{p^2})^{-1}$ and I know the first one behaves like $O(\log{x})$ when over all p, so I'm trying to use the fact about half of all primes are of the first congruence and half the other to somehow reach the final result.

Comment: Ah, great. Indeed, it is an "elementary" result that your first product is asymptotic to a particular constant time $\sqrt{\log x}$. (See for example Corollary 4.12(d) in Montgomery/Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory*, or search for "Mertens product in arithmetic progressions".)